# How to get Hyper-V to recognize that a VM isn't stopping, it's stopped

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V virtual machine that has some problems.

First, its settings are apparently corrupt:

- The WMI object contained an invalid value in property BIOSNumLock.
- The WMI object contained an invalid value in property AutomaticStartupAction.

Second, I saw something that implied that I could toggle the NumLock checkbox on the BIOS property page to fix the first problem, but the checkbox didn't show up. So I connected to the VM and shut it down. Now (many hours later) Hyper-V claims that the VM is "Stopping". However, when I follow the interweb's directions on forcing a VM offline (i.e. find vmwp and kill it), I can't find vmwp. The VM's WMI object has a PID that doesn't exist, and none of the vmwp processes have this machine's GUID.

So, how do I trick Hyper-V into seeing that the machine is offline (or letting me delete it)?

Comment: What does it do if you reboot the server?

Comment: I haven't tried that -- I was trying to avoid doing that, in fact. Now, the VM is "Saved", but I can't delete the VM or the saved state.